# What is multiplying matrices used for?

Tags: matrices

As I am not in the real world yet, I would like to know what multiplying matrices are used for in the real world. I know that to multiply the matrices $(2 \times 2):$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ae+bg&af+bh\\ce+dg&cf+dh\end{bmatrix}$$

How is this used in real life? I just want *one* fully explained example.

P.S. I have a hunch that it is going to be something to do with compression, or just IT, but I can't be sure

Comment: Error correcting codes are one example.

Comment: Matrices represent linear transformations. Multiplication corresponds to composition of linear transformations. For example, to obtain the matrix of a complicated geometrical transformation, one may compute the product of the matrices of simpler operations (rotations, reflections, shear transformations).

Comment: Another example is in Markov chains. Imagine you have a system with $n$ states, and you have some chance of transitioning between various states at each step. The probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ in one step is listed in the $(i,j)$ entry of the $n \times n$ transition matrix $M$. If you want to know the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ in two steps, well that's the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix $M^2$, etc. The matrix keeps track of all the probabilities for you.

Comment: @AlexProvost, Your comment should be an answer. This is immediately what I thought of.